# Hard drive not detected by Mac or Windows machine

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, mac, external-hard-drive, usb-3

I have a 6 month old WD My passport Ultra 1TB that connects to my PC/mac via USB 3.0 Ever since I updated my Mac Book Pro, the drive has become useless. This was four months ago. I have waited so long because I only recently acquired a Windows machine to call my own and attempted to locate it on there. Sadly, on both my apple and windows machines, I cannot see the drive. Not in Mac's `diskutil list` or windows's `diskpart list disk`.

Thus I am putting out a call for assistance with repair of my drive. It had a few backups on it that I have since ceased to care about, anything that returns access to the 1TB of space on the drive, data or no, will do.

Feel free to suggest a solution that works on either Mac or Windows. I have access to machines of both types.

Comment: Can it be seen if you remove it from the case & connect directly to SATA? That would at least hone down whether it was the case or drive. [BTW, the format may appear to be broken if you do that, because of the way some cases show a 'fake' block size to the OS. That wouldn't mean the drive was broken, merely mis-formatted without it's 'translator']

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah already tried that. Grabbed a spudger and popped the case of the drive open. funny thing, WD has made drives where the drive interfaces directly to USB 3.0! No intermediate adapter needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with WD My Passport 1TB when connected via USB3 cable. Disk spins but is not detected on Windows. I checked with several good USB 3.0 cables (USB3 Type-A to Type Micro-B Super Speed). It was a surprise for me, when I connected disk via USB 2.0 cable (with USB Micro port) and it is detected by Windows and I can copy all files from it. Seems that USB2 part of disk adapter is still alive.

**My solution was as follows:**

Connect your laptop to power source to have reliable voltage for external HDD. Then connect your disk with short and heavy USB2.0 cable to laptop.

I want to note, that it is very unreliable solution to produce portable disks without internal SATA interface, so one cannot replace disk enclosure if it is failed, when disk still alive.